# JavaScript Form Validation only Depends on first element

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

My java-script works and all but the only problem is when the first and last name is correct it automatically ignores all the other form element and submits the form. But if the name elements are incorrect it validates the whole form. How do I get it to continue validating if first and last name is correct?

HTML:

```
<form method="post" class="anform" onsubmit="return formCheck()">

<fieldset class="an2fieldset">
<legend class="an2legend">Your Personal Details</legend>

<p><label for="afname">Your First Name:</label></p>
<p><input type="text" size="40" name="afname" id="afname" placeholder="First 
Name" class="an2input"/></p>

<p><label for="alname">Your Last Name:</label></p>
<p><input type="text" size="40" name="alname" id="alname" placeholder="Last 
Name" class="an2input"/></p>

<p><label for="aemail">Your Email:</label></p>
<p><input type="text" name="aemail" size="40" id="aemail" 
placeholder="abcdefgh@gmail.com" class="an2input"/></p>

</fieldset>

<fieldset class="an2fieldset">
<legend class="an2legend">Your Address Detail</legend>

<p><label for="address">Street Adress:</label></p>
<p><input type="text" name="adress" size="40" id="address" 
class="an2input"/></p>

<p><label for="town">City/Town:</label></p>
<p><input type="text" name="acity" size="40" id="town" class="an2input"/>
</p>

<p><label for="state">State:</label></p>
<p class="select">
<select name="state" id="states">
<option value="">--State--</option>
<option value="johor">Johor</option>
<option value="kedah">Kedah</option>
<option value="Kelantan">Kelantan</option>
<option value="Melaka">Melaka</option>
<option value="negeri">Negeri</option>
<option value="Pahang">Pahang</option>
<option value="Perak">Perak</option>
<option value="perlis">Perlis</option>
<option value="penang">Penang</option>
<option value="sabah">Sabah</option>
<option value="sarawak">Sarawak</option>
<option value="selangor">Selangor</option>
<option value="terengganu">Terengganu</option>
<option value="kuala">Kuala Lumpur</option>
<option value="labuan">Labuan</option>
<option value="putrajaya">Putrajaya</option>
</select>
</p>

<p><label for="postcode">Postcode:</label></p>
<p><input type="text" size="5" name="apostcode" id="postcode" 
class="an2input"/></p>

</fieldset>

<fieldset class="an2fieldset">
<legend class="an2legend" id="ye">Your Enquiry</legend>

<p><label for="phone">Phone Number:</label></p>
<p><input type="text" name="phonenumber" size="40" id="phone" 
placeholder="1712345678" class="an2input"/></p>

<p><label for="product">Product:</label></p>
<p class="select">
<select name="product" id="product" >
<optgroup label="Apartment">
<option value="apartment1" id="apartment1" name="pro[]">Apartment 1</option>
<option value="apartment2" id="apartment2" name="pro[]">Apartment 2</option>
<option value="apartment3" id="apartment3" name="pro[]">Apartment 3</option>
<option value="apartment4" id="apartment4" name="pro[]">Apartment 4</option>
<option value="apartment5" id="apartment5" name="pro[]">Apartment 5</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="House">
<option value="house1" id="house1" name="pro[]">House 1</option>
<option value="house2" id="house2" name="pro[]">House 2</option>
<option value="house3" id="house3" name="pro[]">House 3</option>
<option value="house4" id="house4" name="pro[]">House 4</option>
<option value="house5" id="house5" name="pro[]">House 5</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Room">
<option value="room1" id="room1" name="pro[]">Room 1</option>
<option value="room2" id="room2" name="pro[]">Room 2</option>
<option value="room3" id="room3" name="pro[]">Room 3</option>
<option value="room4" id="room4" name="pro[]">Room 4</option>
<option value="room5" id="room5" name="pro[]">Room 5</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Student Room">
<option value="sroom1" id="sroom1" name="pro[]">Student Room 1</option>
<option value="sroom2" id="sroom2" name="pro[]">Student Room 2</option>
<option value="sroom3" id="sroom3" name="pro[]">Student Room 3</option>
<option value="sroom4" id="sroom4" name="pro[]">Student Room 4</option>
<option value="sroom5" id="sroom5" name="pro[]">Student Room 5</option>
</optgroup>
</select>

</p>

<p><label for="duration">Rental Duration:</label></p>
<p><input type="text" id="duration" class="an2input"/></p>

<p><label for="comment">Comment:</label></p>
<textarea class="an2textarea" name="acomment" cols="40" rows="20" 
id="comment" ></textarea> 
</fieldset>

<p><input type="submit" value="Send Enquiry" id="an2submit" 
class="an2input"/></p>

</form>
```

Java:

```
var errormsg = "";
function formCheck()
{
var AllOK = false;

var nameOK = cname();
var emailOK = cemail();
var addOK = cadd();
var cityOK = ccity();
var statesOK = cstates();
var pcodeOK = cpcode();
var hpOK = chp();
var productOK = cproduct();
var durationOK = cduration();

if(nameOK && emailOk && addOK && cityOK && statesOK && pcodeOK && hpOK && 
productOK && durationOK)
{
    AllOk = true;
}

else
{
    alert(errormsg);
    errormsg = "";
    AllOK = false;
}

return AllOK;
} 

function cname()
{
var fname = document.getElementById("afname").value;
var lname = document.getElementById("alname").value;
var namepat = /^[a-zA-z ]*$/;


if(fname == "")
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Your first name must not be empty\n";
    return false;
}

if(lname == "")
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Your last name must not be empty\n";
    return false;
}

if(!fname.match(namepat))
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Your name must only contain letters A-Z\n";
    return false;
}

if(!lname.match(namepat))
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Your name must only contain letters A-Z\n";
    return false;
}

if(fname.length > 25)
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Your Name is too long\n";
    return false;
}

if(lname.length > 25)
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Your Name is too long\n";
    return false;
}

else
{
    return true;
}
}

function cemail()
{
var email = document.getElementById("aemail").value;
var emailpat =  /[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/;


if(email == "")
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Please Enter your E-mail\n";
    return false;
}

if(!email.match(emailpat))
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Please Enter a valid E-mail\n";
    return false;
}

else
{
    return true;
}   
}

function cadd()
{
var add = document.getElementById("address").value;

if(add == "")
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Please Enter your Address\n";
    return false;
}

if(add.length > 40)
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Your Address is too long\n";
    return false;
}

else
{
    return true;
}
}

function ccity()
{
var city = document.getElementById("town").value;

if(city == "")
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Please Enter your City/Town\n";
    return false;
}

if(city.length > 20)
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Your City/Town is too long\n";
    return false;
}

else
{
    return true;
}
}

function cstates()
{
var state = document.getElementById("states").value;

if(states.selectedIndex == 0)
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Please Select your State\n";
    return false;
}

else
{
    return true;
}
}

function cpcode()
{   
var pcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;

if(pcode == "")
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Please Enter your Post Code\n";
    return false;
}

if(pcode.length != 5)
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Please enetr a 5-digit Post Code\n";
    return false;
}

else
{
    return true;
}
}

function chp()
{
var hp = document.getElementById("phone").value;
var nopat = /^[0-9]+$/;


if(hp == "")
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Please Enter your Phone Number\n";
    return false;
}

if(!hp.match(nopat))
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Your Phone Number must only be numbers\n";
    return false;
}

if(hp.length > 10)
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Please Enter a 10-digit Phone Number\n";
    return false;
}

else
{
    return true;
}   
}

function cproduct()
{
var product = document.getElementsByName("pro[]");

var i=0;
var error=false;
for (i=0;i<product.length;i++){
    if (product[i].selected==true){
        error=true;
    }
}
if (error == false){
    errormsg = errormsg+"You have to select a product\n";
}
return error;

}

function cduration()
{
var duration = document.getElementById("duration").value;
var nopat = /^[0-9]+$/;

if(duration == "" || duration.length < 1)
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Please Enter a Duration\n";
    return false;
}

if(!duration.match(nopat))
{
    errormsg = errormsg + "Duration must only be in numbers\n";
    return false;
}

else
{
    return true;
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you correctly enter a first name and a last name, I see this error in my console:

> ReferenceError: emailOk is not defined

I think that you made a typo.

`emailOk` should be `emailOK`

Change this line:
`if(nameOK && emailOk && addOK && cityOK && statesOK && pcodeOK && hpOK &&`

to this line:
`if(nameOK && emailOK && addOK && cityOK && statesOK && pcodeOK && hpOK &&`

Comment: Oh my God. Thanksss! Thank You Soo Much!! It works now :)